# replace all tokens from a config file using a property file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

Could some one help me to build a unix shell script for the below scenario.

**environment.properties :**

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
KEY3=VALUE3
KEY4=VALUE4
KEY5=VALUE5
KEY6=VALUE6
```

**input.txt :**

```
sample file contains KEY1 
sample file contains KEY2 
sample file contains KEY3 
sample file contains KEY4 
sample file contains KEY5
```

**output.txt :**

```
sample file contains VALUE1 
sample file contains VALUE2 
sample file contains VALUE3 
sample file contains VALUE4 
sample file contains VALUE5
```

I would like to apply property file to my input.txt, and wanted to replace all tokens and generate an output file.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51022517/edit) and I'll retract my close vote. With a bash tag in your question, I'd expect to see some bash code.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT2:*** Adding ghoti sir's answer too here.

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for(i in a){gsub(i,a[i])}} 1' mapfile inputfile
```

---

***EDIT:*** As per @ghoti sir's suggestion not hard coding the string `KEY` field number here it will look for string and change it then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/KEY[0-9]+/){$i=a[$i]}}} 1' FS="=" environment.properties  FS=" " input.txt
```

OR using `match` function of `awk` here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2;
  next}
match($0,/KEY[0-9]+/){
   print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
   next
}
1' FS="=" environment.properties  FS=" " input.txt
```

---

This is a task for `awk`, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {$NF=a[$NF]} 1' FS="=" environment.properties  FS=" " input.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
sample file contains VALUE1
sample file contains VALUE2
sample file contains VALUE3
sample file contains VALUE4
sample file contains VALUE5
```

Comment: @SURESH K, try to select an answer as correct answer(out of all answers) to complete the thread.

Comment: This is a good start and a great lesson in how to load variables into awk for processing, but as a more generally useful templating tool, I'd love to see it load keys from the first input file and replace them **anywhere** in the line. A `for` loop through the array running a `gsub` perhaps. That would make your answer applicable for folks who have a *similar* but not *identical* requirement to the OP.

Comment: It was working fine with simple text file but, I would like to apply to an xml file, but which is failing.       <repository xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns = "http://www.tibco.com/xmlns/repo/types/2002">
 <globalVariables>
  <globalVariable>
   <name>//utilityservice.module///utilityservice/SharedResources/Connections/utilityDBConfig/Username</name>
   <value>@UTL_AUDDB_USER@</value>
   <deploymentSettable>false</deploymentSettable>
   <serviceSettable>false</serviceSettable>
   <type>String</type>
   <isOverride>false</isOverride>
  </globalVariable>

Comment: @SURESHK, please do mention same kind of samples which are near to your Input_file so that solutions could be prepared accordingly then. Please post the samples again now.

Comment: @SURESHK - but .. you didn't include an xml file in your question. If the answer provided works perfectly with the data in your question, but not in the data that is not in your question, it's time to close this question and ask a new, better one. (Don't just edit this question, that's not fair to anyone who's already put time into answering your original question.)

Comment: Sorry Mate, I am not able to update the post. Ideally my intention was load the property file and search for each key in the input file and replace it. I would like make it work for any file, If key1 found it replace value1. In the entire file

Comment: @ghoti, sure ghoti sir, ADDED one more solution in EDIT as per your suggestion which will look for string and then change it.

Comment: @SURESHK, please open a new thread(selecting answer as correct or not I leave up to you since your actual Input_file is different), start a fresh thread with all the details and samples and with your efforts to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I was thinking more along the lines of `awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for(i in a){gsub(i,a[i])}} 1' mapfile inputfile`, to support templates that are not distinct fields.

Comment: @ghoti, sure sir, I added your code in my solution too, cheers/